# $_post isset not working. Used the same syntax on other examples and works perfectly. Value not able to be posted for where claus MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Ok so I am trying to select values from a table in mysql using a $_post. Below I have included a basic php file without post that seems to be working fine and returns json as expected with the value of username just manually set.

```
echo "connection";
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","simplifiedcoding") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db

    echo "statement";

    $sql = "select * from volley where username = 'cmac '";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

//create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($emparray);




//close the db connection
mysqli_close($connection);
```

But then when I try to set the value of username with $_Post in another tester file it doesnt work. The value is not being set as seen below. The code is meant to check if the username has been set, then execute the function using the set data.I really dont know where this is going on and I appreciate that this is a common subject matter but I have no idea what is causing this to not be set.

```
    require_once 'connection.php';

    class Get_game
    {

        private $db;
        private $connection;

        function __construct()
        {

            $this->db = new DB_Connection();
            $this->connection = $this->db->get_connection();
            echo "connected";
        }

        public function get_game_id($username)
        {

            echo "query";
            //$query = "select * from volley";
            $query = "select game_id from volley WHERE username = '".$username."'";

            echo "result";

            $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query) or die ("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($this->connection));

            //create an array
            $emparray = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $emparray[] = $row;
            }
            return json_encode($emparray);

            //close the db connection
            mysqli_close($this->connection);

        }
    }


    echo "class";

    $game = new Get_game();

    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        echo "set";

        if (!empty($username)) {
            $game->get_game_id($username);
        } else {
            echo("error");
        }

    }
```

I have looked on previous answers on here but nothing seems to work. It is also quite annoying that I have other files with the same syntax but different variables to $_post that are working fine. I included a couple of echos to see where the code was failing as no errors are showing. The code creates the class fine but wont set the values.  I will include a file that works fine with the same syntax below. I just can't figure out why one piece of code works fine in one instance and seems to not work at all in another with barely anything being changed.The first snippet of code works fine but I want to be able to execute the querying with a $_post value. I have tried different ways of doing this and none of them seem to work. The code is meant to return json and display it. The first snippet of code does this perfectly. I know that there is something wrong withh the $_post and issett() but i cannot figure it out

Comment: Can you post the code where you are filling the username of POST please ?

Comment: I will now I have been using postman

Comment: Is there a `username` field in the POST values?  With all these `echo` statements, which ones are you seeing?  Where is the code actually failing?  Also note that your code is *wide open* to SQL injection, so you could be executing anything in that SQL code.

Comment: localhost/simplifiedcoding/fetchUser.php?username=cmac

Comment: and the response is 'classconnected'. Thats when i used the fetch User.php file

Comment: That's a `$_GET` request, not `$_POST`. Also, while looking for/debugging unset variables, using `isset` is really the last thing you want to do (it's just obstructing the notices you should be looking for). `var_dump` GET, POST and _SERVER environment vars instead.

Comment: @cmc12345: That's a GET value, not a POST value.

Comment: so I've changed the post to get but its still not working. Not showing the json, just the echos

Comment: Thank you both for your replies

Comment: change `return json_encode($emparray);` to `echo json_encode($emparray);`

Comment: perfect thank you so much ! i know alot on here wouldnt give an answer so i appreciate it. I just didnt get why post worked for another file but thank you !!

Comment: is there any reason why i cant $_post the data? sorry i am new to this. But I want to be able to then get the data into android and it seems to be that post is the way to do it only post does not work on the php file